# Change height of child element on button/link press using ::before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got an Org Chart that will run on mobile devices nearly completely different from how it runs on desktop. Everything is as it should be with one minor problem. My Org Chart features the ability to click a person which then slides an accordion down to provide more information about that particular person along with contact information. This feature is great on desktop but when it runs to mobile, my connectors are based on fixed values in the CSS. I need the `::before` height to be changed when the accordion is extended to counter this. I've provided photos below for further clarification.

Images of before and after: http://imgur.com/a/x7JSn

Now my main concern is that I've put myself in a position where I'll have to write totally different functions for each element in order for that particular element to connect.

Here's how my HTML is laid out:

```
<ul>
    <li class="director">
        <div id="ss_menu">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ss_button">
                <span class="title">Director </span><br/>
                <span class="sm-hide">Name of Person</span>
            </a>
            <div class="ss_content">
                <img src="img/person.jpg"
                 width="70px"
                 style="border: 1px solid #000;"/><br/>
                Telephone: 555-555-5555<br/>
                Email: emailaddress@email.com<br/>
                Room: A123<br/>
                Mail Stop: A123
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div id="ss_menu">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ss_button">
                        <span class="title">Assistant to the Director </span><br/>
                        <span class="sm-hide">Name of Person</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="ss_content">
                        <img src="img/person.jpg"
                         width="70px"
                         style="border: 1px solid #000;"/><br/>
                        Telephone: 555-555-5556<br/>
                        Email: emailaddress@email.com<br/>
                        Room: A124<br/>
                        Mail Stop: A124
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul>
<! -- THE CODE CONTINUES FOR A WHILE BUT IS LAID OUT THE SAME WAY -->
```

And then here is the general layout of the vertical lines using the ::before keyword:

```
.director::before {
  content: "";
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  height: 165px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.deputydirector::before {
  content: "";
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1442px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

I'm essentially trying to increase the height of the vertical lines by the amount that the accordion opens.

Lastly here is the jQuery code I'm using for the accordion which I'd like to use as a catch-all for managing my vertical lines as well.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.ss_button').on('click',function() {
        jQuery('.ss_content').slideUp('fast');
        jQuery(this).next('.ss_content').slideDown('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: First thing you should do is fix your HTML, you are missing 2 closing `li` tags and 2 closing `ul` tags as well as an unnecessary opening `ul` tag.

Comment: I would also suggest using a different approach to your jQuery. Currently, if you click on an `li` where the `ss_content` element is already open, it will close and then immediately reopen.

Comment: Well this is just an excerpt of my code. It is a lot longer than that; however, that is the same format as the other so I didn't feel a need to give you 360 lines of the same. Secondly, the jQuery is kind of a placeholder right now in that I'll polish it after I get main design stuff done.